# Dropbox DBRestClient/DBRestClientDelegate execute on a thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox API with DBRESTClient and DBRestClientDelegate in Dropbox-iOS-SDK

My issue is that I need these to run on a background thread.

When I call the [restClient loadMetadata] I do not get a response to - restClient:loadedMetadata: unless I begin call from the main thread.

Is there a simple workaround/library that I can use which will allow a delegate response on a thread ?    I have tried Dropblocks which uses blocks but no luck.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this on a background thread?

Comment: Because it is impacting my UI. Why wouldn't someone prefer downloads in  a background thread ?

Comment: I guess I'm confused because the download happens on a background thread no matter what. It's typical to call it from your UI thread and receive the delegate there.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed "Make sure you call DBRestClient methods from the main thread or a thread that has a run loop. Otherwise the delegate methods won't be called." on the Dropbox Page
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/ios

I used a runloop and it functions on a thread now

This is using a completion block Similarly you could use the delegate to set the flag to NO

```
self.inQuery = YES;
[self loadMetaDataWithPath:rootFolder mediaType:@(mediaType) completion:^(BOOL complete) {
    self.inQuery = NO;
}];

@autoreleasepool {
    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        DDLogError(@"currentRunLoop %@",[NSDate date]);
    }while(self.inQuery);
}
```